# Date format regex testing in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, regex

Date is stored in my MySql db field like that: `20160816` /* YearMonthDay*/

How do I search for entries by month?

Tried the following regex sql query to search for entries which has month (08) but no luck:

```
SELECT FROM posts WHERE posts.meta_key = 'start_date' AND (CAST(posts.meta_value AS CHAR) REGEXP '\\d{4}08\\d{2}')
```

Comment: Or you could just store them as proper date/datetime fields and then do `where month(yourfield) = 8`... And you really should look up mysql's regex syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp   what you're doing is not how mysql does them.

Comment: MySQL regex engine does not support `\d`. Use `[0-9]`

Comment: I can't make a new field in the db. I have to use it just like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Could you please post the full SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: Try `REGEXP '[0-9]{4}08[0-9]{2}'`. This should work with text data.

Comment: Great! Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you run a regex on text  data.

Then, note you can match a digit with `[0-9]` pattern, or `[[:digit:]]`.

Thus, use

```
REGEXP '[0-9]{4}08[0-9]{2}'‌​
```

to get your entries containing four digits followed with `08` and then two digits.